# node-mysql escaping query values - array with unknown length

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I use node.js and the module node-mysql for connecting to the mySQL server. However, I got some problems when I tried to escape an array in a query. Here is my code:

```
connection.query("select * from table where id in (?)", [1, 3, 5], function(err, res) {
    ...
});
```

The above query is `select * from table where id in (1)`, which is not my expectation.

As the documents said:

`Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'`

I know `select * from table where id in (?,?,?)` works. The question is, what should I do if I have an array with unknown length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to nest the array so that it gets properly converted to a list:

```
connection.query("select * from table where id in (?)", [[1, 3, 5]], ...);
```

Another solution would be to dynamically generate the `?`s. For example:

```
var values = [1, 3, 5];
var query = "select * from table where id in ("
            + new Array(values.length + 1).join('?,').slice(0, -1)
            + ")";
connection.query(query, values, function(err, res) {
    ...
});
```

With ES6, you can simplify the list creation in the second solution to:

```
'?,'.repeat(values.length).slice(0, -1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I can generate numbers of `?` base on length on the array, which is pure javascript approach. I am looking for some higher level solutions. I will use your method if there is no better way.

Comment: i had the same id using lodash functions: `_.times(ids.length, _.constant('?')).join()`. and then passing the array like: `query(query, ids, function...)`. But your approach is much cleaner.